# Format SVN diff as a side-by-side comparison

Tags: unix, svn, console, diff

I wanted to produce a side by side SVN diff instead of the usual SVN diff output.
Is there any way to get this sort of output ?

Comment: What SVN client are you using?

Comment: I am not using any client. I am running it from the console. I want the diff to be reproducible. So, I need the output produced from a command which I can run from a script.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can specify a custom diff command:

```
svn --diff-cmd "diff" --extensions "-y" diff
```

(Or then perhaps even use tools like sdiff)

Comment: I just want only the differences side by side. Is there any way to do that ? The above command compares the entire file.

Comment: @Prakashkumar: Adding `--suppress-common-lines` to the extensions argument will probably do that. (`--extensions "-y --suppress-common-lines"`)

Answer (score 6):

`cdiff` can display **side by side**, **incremental**, and **colorful** diff, see its home page for detail and demo at https://github.com/ymattw/cdiff

Comment: this tool is amazing, it's definitely going to be in my daily routine now.

Answer (score 4):

svn diff --diff-cmd 'diff' -x '--side-by-side -W230' FILENAME

Tune the "-W230" to whatever takes full use of your screen width