# svn how to display content of file in repository, ignoring local changes

Tags: svn

I want to view a file as it looks in the repository without local modifications.

I don't want to discard my local changes, I just want to do a side by side comparison between a terminal and a text editor.

I'm aware that diff can do [a side-by-side comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835469/format-svn-diff-as-a-side-by-side-comparison), but I don't want that, I just want to see the repository version of a file in a terminal without local changes - is this possible?

I'm on linux, so I need to know the shell command, I can't use tortoise/similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer on SO, relating to viewing an older version of a file.

The accepted answer helped:

```
svn cat -r 666 file | less
```

using -r HEAD instead gives me what I wanted.

I think this should be listed in the svn --help page :)